# Nodejs - HTTP Range support / Partial file download

Tags: node.js, http-headers, gridfs

I am creating a music web app that streams MP3s that I have stored in MongoDB(GridFS).

My Question: How can I add http range support so that I can start streaming the audio file 1/2 of the way through without having to wait for the buffer.

I know GridFS supports reading for X bytes - X bytes, so basically I just need to know how to get nodejs to understand it only needs bytes X - X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The client will send a `Range` header specifying the absolute starting and ending bytes followed by total file length or '*'.

#### Examples:

```
  . The first 500 bytes:
   bytes 0-499/1234

  . The second 500 bytes:
   bytes 500-999/1234

  . All except for the first 500 bytes:
   bytes 500-1233/1234

  . The last 500 bytes:
   bytes 734-1233/1234
```

The server should then return a response code `206` (Partial content) and the `Content-Length` should be only the amount of data transmitted.

In the case the range is wrong, the server should either return `416` (Requested range not satisfiable) with a `Content-Range` field of `bytes */*` or should ignore the range request and return a `200` with the entire body of the file.

The server must also send an `Accept-Ranges` field with the value of the accepted range unit, in this case `bytes`. But the range unit can be any custom range unit you want.

Source: [rfc2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.16)

Comment: I believe client should send a `Range` header instead of `Content-Range`. Latter is sent in by the server in the response.

Comment: In ExpressJS, needs to be `Range` not `Content-Range`